# I am trying to make candlestick graphs, but even though the code appears to work, the charts don’t show up anywhere

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, finance, candlestick-chart

Full disclosure - I'm very new to coding, I suspect the answer here could be rather simple (maybe somewhere charts should show up? I've made graphs in the past that have showed up though...), but I've spent probably a dozen hours trying different methods of printing candlestick charts. I mostly use [Spyder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spyder_%28software%29), but I tried using [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs) thinking maybe the IDE was the problem. I also tried [Jupyter Notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter), but I couldn’t figure out the interface.

I've tried making the graph using [Plotly](https://pypi.org/project/plotly/) and with mpl finance.

The closest I seemed to get was to get a blank chart (which seemed weird since I definitely had data in the dataframe. I’m also not sure how I got that, because I can’t get it any more.

This is the code I tried with Plotly:

```
import datetime as dt

import pandas as pd

from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

import plotly.graph_objects as go

from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

import plotly.io as pio

pio.renderers.default = 'svg'

start = dt.datetime(2015, 2, 2)
end = "2022-08-01"

stock = ["AAPL"]

stock = pdr.DataReader(stock, 'yahoo', start, end)
print(stock.head())

ma50 = stock['Close'].rolling(window=50, min_periods=0).mean()

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True,vertical_spacing = .01, subplot_titles = ('price','volumne'))

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=stock.index,
                                     open=stock['Open'],
                                     high=stock['High'],
                                     low=stock['Low'],
                                     close=stock['Close'])])
```

---

This was the output:

> Process finished with exit code 0

So I get that exit code 0 means there were no errors, but why is there also no graph, and how do I get the graph?

(Separately, why didn’t drop.na() remove the NaNs on the 50 day moving average?)

Comment: are you running this as a script, rather than in an interactive session? if so... yeah you'll need to save your fig objects, or explicitly display them with [`matplotlib.pyplot.show`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html)

Comment: also - if you have two questions, please ask two questions :) see the guide to [ask]. in order to help understand what's going on with your data workflow, we'll need to see the data you're working with. ideally, provide a [mre], but at the very least make sure to include the relevant section of code and describe exactly what's happening and what's not working. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why the graph is not displayed is due to the SVG specification. I don't know why, I tried running it several times in jupyterlab environment, but it kept freezing. You can get the candlestick graph by disabling `pio.renderers.default = 'svg'`.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.io as pio

# pio.renderers.default = 'svg'

start = dt.datetime(2015, 2, 2)
end = "2022-08-01"

stock = ["AAPL"]

stock = pdr.DataReader(stock, 'yahoo', start, end)
print(stock.head())

ma50 = stock['Close'].rolling(window=50, min_periods=0).mean()
stock.columns = stock.columns.droplevel(level=1)

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing=.3, subplot_titles=('price','volumne'))

fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=stock.index,
                             open=stock['Open'],
                             high=stock['High'],
                             low=stock['Low'],
                             close=stock['Close'],
                             name='Candlestick'),
              row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=stock.index, y=stock['Volume'], name='Volume'), row=2,col=1)
fig.update_layout(autosize=True, height=600)

# fig.write_image("data/fig1.svg")
fig.show()
```

[image]